# Serial to USD (HID keyboard device) converter

Tags: serial, usb, hid

I am working on a project to collect data from a barcode scanner using an Arduino, which in turn is connected to a POS/laptop. So far I am able to collect the data from the barcode scanner by using the Arduino as a host, and in order to send the scanner data from the Arduino to the laptop, I am using a [basic FTDI board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9716) that converts serial data from the arduino to USB.

However, it shows up as a COM port in my computer and I need an additional serial monitor to see the data transferred from the Arduino.

Is there a device that converts serial data from the arduino to "HID keyboard Device" similar to the FTDI board?

Please let me know if I have not made myself clear or if you need more information.

Edit: I forgot to add that I am using an [Arduino MKR NB 1500](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-mkr-nb-1500-1413). I am using the board's native USB port to connect to the barcode scanner. [The USBHost library](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/USBHost) gives the board the ability to act as a USB host and connect to the barcode scanner and get the scanned data from the barcode scanner.

I am using the FTDI board (serial to USB converter) and arduino's serial1 to send the scanned data to my laptop.

We are trying to build a portable device that connects to the barcode scanner and the POS. We are using the Arduino to update our database (I can use the MKR board to send a POST request with the barcode data to update our database) and in addition to this the Arduino should be able to send the scanned data to POS.
As of now I am connecting the Arduino's RX and TX pins to the FTDI board, which converts UART to USB. I would like to replace this FTDI board with an interface that converts UART to "USB HID keyboard". Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: you could use a scanner which has SPI or Serial interface and let the USB free for keypad emulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I would like to replace this FTDI board with an interface that converts UART to "USB HID keyboard".**

[image: FTDI Friend and ATmega32u4 board]

On the left is an "FTDI Friend" that converts serial to USB. It is similar to the Sparkfun product you are using.

On the right is a similar sized, similar priced, board that can read serial and can act as a USB keyboard (Implementing the appropriate HID). It's a [Pololu A*Star micro](https://www.pololu.com/product/3101) but it's just one example of many similar devices. I used this one to implement a physical keyboard using mechanical switches but the input could have as easily come from it's serial interface.

Any ATmega32u4 or SAMD based board can act as a USB HID keyboard using the standard [Arduino keyboard library](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/usb/keyboard/)

Admittedly you'll have to write and upload a sketch but that ought to be relatively straightforward.

There are also smaller, potentially cheaper, boards such as the Digispark and clones that have a separate software library to implement USB HID Keyboard functionality on a very simple microcontroller like the ATtiny85.

---

> **We are trying to build a portable device that connects to the barcode scanner and the POS.**

As Juraj's comment suggests, many barcode readers started out as serial devices and only later had USB-serial capability added. If you use a Barcode scanner with serial output, you probably don't need any extra hardware and can use the MKR NB 1500's USB interface to act as a keyboard device instead of as a host for the scanner.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I will try with Attiny85 and 32U4 Micro boards and see how it goes. Unfortunately, i have to work with USB barcode scanners and I am using the arduino board's native USB to get the data from the barcode scanner.

Answer (score 0):

use CH9329 chip it's cheap and could act as Keyboard and mouse at the same time. interface is a little bit hard as it's Chinese but it's cost 1 USD only.